# how to save related models with non-null foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have two models:

User

```
has_one :email
```

Email

```
belongs_to :user
```

I put the email_id foreign key (NOT NULL) inside users table.
Now I'm trying to save it in the following way:

```
@email = Email.new(params[:email])
@email.user = User.new(params[:user])
@email.save
```

This raises a db exception, because the foreign key constraint is not met (NULL is inserted into email_id). How can I elegantly solve this or is my data modeling wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected.

```
@email = Email.create(params[:email])
@email.user.create(params[:user])
```

Comment: Basically you're suggesting to save @email first. Afterwards save @user and thus the relationship between the two. Does someone have other ideas or a different way to code this?

Comment: Yes, if you don't save Email you won't get the id that is needed for email_id field of User, and you won't be able to validate User.

Answer (score 1):

Hum...
Do you have

```
has_one :email
```

in your user model?

If it's the case, I think there is a problem. You should use has_one in the user model if it's the email table that has the foreign_key.

You should have a user_id column in the email table I think.

Comment: You're right, I should have the foreign key in the model that has a belongs_to declaration.