# How to set a foreign key in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to save a object that has a foreign key attribute. I do not understand why it's not working. The foreign key is defined as not null in the database.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :description
  validates :store_group, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 500}
  validates :latitude,    :presence => true
  validates :longitude,   :presence => true

  belongs_to :store_group
end

class StoreGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :image
  validates :name, :presence => { :message => "Store group can not be empty" }
end
```

So, I'm trying to save a store:

```
group = StoreGroup.new(:name=>"name",:description=>"description",:image=>"image")
store = Store.new(:store_group=>group,:latitude=>1,:longitude=>1,:description=>"description")
store.save
```

However, MySQL raises an exception:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'store_group' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `stores` (`created_at`, `store_group`, `description`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-02-17 04:09:15', NULL, 'description', 1.0, 1.0, '2013-02-17 04:09:15')
```

Why?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tried Store.new(:store_group=>group.id...) too, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it may be easier in the long run if you add a `has_many :stores` to StoreGroup, for instance if you ever want to retrieve all of the stores that belong to a particular StoreGroup. Secondly, you should add the store via its StoreGroup, and since you already have an association there it's fairly straightforward (note the change to `Store.create`):

```
group = StoreGroup.create(name: "name", description: "description", image: "image")
group.stores << Store.create(lat: 1, long: 1, desc: "description")
```

This method will automatically set `:store_group_id` and save the new Store instance as a "child" of its StoreGroup. Note that you'll also want to change your code to account for existing StoreGroups, so that you can add stores to existing StoreGroups later. Using `.first_or_create` with a `.where(...)` clause is idiomatic for rails 3.2.x, though there are dynamic finders with create powers in previous versions of Rails (find_or_create_by_name_and_store_group_id, as an example).

Lastly, remove `validates :store_group` because association validations don't work that way. If you really must, use `validates :store_group_id`.

Comment: Hi Eric, firstly thank you for the tips. I added has_many in StoreGroup and replaced the validates for store_group_id. So, I tried what you said, but after this command `"group.stores << Store.create(lat: 1, long: 1, desc: "description")"` it raised the same exception.

One thing that I should mistaking either, the column in the table Store for StoreGroup object should be store_group or store_group_id? I'm using store_group, I don't know if this could be a problem for ActiveRecord relationships..

Comment: Sorry, in my example I used `StoreGroup.new` where .new isn't going to save the instance and so no ID will be available when the Store is assigned to it. It should be `StoreGroup.create`. I've edited my example to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create/save `store_group` object through `store`. Thus use:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :store_group
```

in your `Store` model

[Read  here about accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Hi Rahul, I tried but when I'm instantiating store oject it raises ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: store_group. So, I added store_group in attr_accessbile, however, the previous MySQL exception still raising.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8321540/985051

You need to add your association attrs to attr_accessors

Comment: I solved using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912154/how-to-save-related-models-with-non-null-foreign-key

Comment: Its ok... but here storeGroup and store would be created under different transaction, so if there are any validations error in creating `store` your `storegroup` would still be commited to database.